# Permission on Android Detox

Tags: android, react-native, detox

As the title said it all. I have been finding the way to enable permission like 'Drawing over other apps' for Android using Detox. I think the behaviour would be similar with Permission in iOS but I can't seem to find out any document.[image: drawing over other apps]

Answer (score 0):

Recently react-native removed the need of this permission, so you don't need to accept it anymore.